# why ajax call behaves strange in similar situation?

Tags: php, ajax, include, behavior

I'm using ajax call in my login.php twice and call ajax.php with two different parameter:

login.php

```
$(function()
 { $("#slctSys").focusin(function() 
                  { $.get("ajax.php"
                          ,{sysuser:$("#sysUser").val(), sysupw:$("#sysPswd").val()}
                          ,function(data1) {$("#slctSys").html(data1); }); 
                   })
                 .change(function() 
                   { $.get("ajax.php"
                           ,{sysid:$("#slctSys").val()}
                           ,function(data2) {$("#divURL").text(data2);});
                    });
  });
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
include_once('function.php');

if (isset($_GET['sysuser']))
 { $c=sysSelectDB('sysdb');
   $sysinfo=$c->prepare('select sysname from sysinfo
                   where sysuun = "'.$_GET['sysuser'].'"
                     and sysupw = "'.$_GET['sysupw'].'"');

   $sysinfo->execute();
   $ijk='<option value=-1>Select ...</option>';
   if ($sysinfo->rowCount()>0)
    { while ($data = $sysinfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
       { $ijk.='<option value='.$data['sysid'].'>'.$data['sysname'].'</option>'; }}
   else { $ijk='<option value=-1>No Access !!!</option>'; }
   $sysinfo->closeCursor();
   $c=null;
   echo $ijk; }

if (isset($_GET['sysid']))
 { $c=sysSelectDB('sysdb');
   $s='select * from sysacss where sysid='.$_GET['sysid'];
   $sysinfo=$c->prepare($s);
   $sysinfo->execute();
   if ($sysinfo->rowCount()==1)
    { $data=$sysinfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $retVal=implode("#;#",$data); }
   $sysinfo->closeCursor();
   $c=null;
   echo '$retValsalam'; }
```

I also include a function.php inside of ajax.php as you see:

function.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=content-type>
<LINK    href="/sysdb/resource/sysStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script  src ="/sysdb/resource/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
function timer()
 { var cT=new Date();
   var cH=cT.getHours();
   var cM=cT.getMinutes();
   var cS=cT.getSeconds();
   return (cH<10?"0":"")+cH+(cM<10?":0":":")+cM+(cS<10?":0":":")+cS; }
```

...

On the first ajax call the retrived data is ok. But in the second, the function.php are pre append to returned value. why?

Comment: You have quoting problems in `ajax.php`. Is that in the real script or just a copying error?

Comment: What is `$sysinfo` -- should that be `$s`?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, u r right. it's my mistype. tnx. it's simplified of  my real code.

Comment: Thats a bit strange. Those ajax calls should actually both prepend the lines you're outputting in function.php. You should restucture your code so that you dont include function.php in every ajax call or remove any direct output from function.php

Comment: @MSTannu, any idea about why the fisrt call works fine, but the second not?

Answer (score 0):

i find solution based on your issue @MSTannu. u r right. i just use ob_start() before and ob_end_clean() after include function. and the problem solved. i think that only second call pre append include file into output, but both of ajax calls have the same behavior. tnx.

Comment: Why do you produce output in `function.php` in the first place? If that include file is just for defining functions that are used in your other scripts, that's all it should do. If you have a standard HTML header that you want to use in all your pages, put that in another include file, e.g. `header.php`.